# Linux: recv after close() returns "bad file descriptor"

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I thought that closing a TCP connection (invoking close() on file descriptor) puts it in a state where it stops sending data, but can still receive data until the peer also close its sockets. However, when testing this, I get "Bad File Descriptor" on the recv() call. I would have expected recv() to return with code=0. Note that the select() call succeeded.

```
if (0 != close(sockfd))
{
    err_sys("close failed");
}

printf("select waiting for response\n");
FD_ZERO(&rset);
FD_SET(sockfd, &rset);
wset = rset;

printf("select waiting for response\n");
if ((stat = select(sockfd + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == 0)
{
    errno = ETIMEDOUT;
    err_sys("connect timed out");
}
printf("got response\n");

stat = recv(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
if (0 == stat) {
    printf("remote closed\n");
}
else if (-1 == stat) {
    if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN) {
        err_sys("would block again\n");
    } else {
        err_sys("recv failed");
    }
} else {
    err_sys("unexpected return code");
}
```

Comment: No, it does't do that. You've described `shutdown(sd, SHUT_WR),` not `close().`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)` to close only for writes but still be able to read.  `close(fd)` will invalidate the file descriptor just as if you had closed an open path to a local file.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html